# SOLR how to match concatenated words?

Tags: mysql, apache, search, solr

I setup my SOLR search and i can finally get suggestions from spell check but I noticed that if search:

> iphone seven

I get the correct results because in my mysql I have the item spelled with separate words but if I search for:

> iphoneseven

I get zero results and zero suggestions.
What should i do to get suggestions when a user writes something in one word?

Comment: I think you need the WordBreakSolrSpellChecker component which can combine or break words. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spell+Checking

Comment: What kind of filter are you using in your schema ? If you are using `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`, you can play with the `concatenateWords` parameter and the `ShingleFilterFactory`!

Comment: i was also thinking to create an index exporting from mysql the concat words in a new column... I will try your suggestions first.. I'm a SOLR newbie, don't know much about it